# Conviniend Re-Deploy Application on Glassfish Server

Tags: deployment, admin, glassfish-3

In the moment the best way to redeploy an application to our glassfish servers is:

1. stop domain (so we don't get lots of exceptions because querys comming in while redeploy)
2. remove the application from the domain folder
3. start domain
4. deploy compelete application

Is there s.t. I miss that would make the process less time consuming.

Thanks Hasan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use NetBeans integrated hot-deployment to deploy faster. NetBeans detects the files that have changed and copies only these to the deployment folder.

To enable explicitly (it should be enabled by default):

1. Go to Project -> Properties -> Build -> Run
2. Enable "Deploy on Save"

Make sure you have the following in your `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You can ignore the exceptions on redeployment.

Another option would be to checkout [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel).

Comment: That servers must be on the same machine or can it also be another machine?

Comment: It can also be a remote server. You have to add a new Server instance in NetBeans and choose "Register Remote Domain".

Comment: Does eclipse also have this kind of "remote" possiblities?